# Place and align images in tables

Tags: tables, includegraphics

I need to align some images with colored borders in my tables, here's what I have so far

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,notitlepage]{article}   % papersize, fontsize, documentclass; 
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttablex}     % to have a dedicated notes section after tables
\usepackage[font=small, margin=0pt]{caption}            % table and figure captions
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}                  % used for table alternatively colors
\usepackage{booktabs}                       % use package booktabs for easy creating tables
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\usepackage{multirow}

% Spacing and margin rules
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
\setlength{\fboxrule}{1pt}%
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{7pt}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{10pt}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{5pt}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\captionsetup[table]{singlelinecheck=false, labelfont={color=black}}  

\begin{document}


\section{Place Images in Table}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{} X|p{0.33\textwidth}|p{0.33\textwidth} @{}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Text} & \textbf{Image} & \textbf{Image} \\
    \endhead
    \midrule
    This is some text that should be top-aligned in the cell with the image center aligned in it's own cell. Let's make it a little bit longer...\newline I always want a little bit more... & \raisebox{-1.5\height}{\includegraphics[scale=1.0, cfbox=red 2pt 2pt, valign=c]{./content/figures/terminate.png}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\raisebox{-2.5\height}{\includegraphics[scale=1.0, cfbox=green 2pt 2pt, valign=c]{./content/figures/terminate.png}}} \\\cline{1-2}
    This might be a row with some less text & \raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[scale=1.0, cfbox=blue 2pt 2pt, valign=c]{./content/figures/terminate.png}} & \\

    \bottomrule
    \caption{Test}
    \label{test}
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

How can I add a minimal margin to the image with the blue border?

This is the picture

[image]

Comment: Which image with the blue border? We have none of the images in your code.

Comment: You did not provide the picture to include...

Comment: I meant the one with `cfbox=blue 2pt 2pt`, this one is top and bottom tight with the border. Picture added...

Comment: Well, you should take a look to the `booktabs` package (I mean: read the doc), since there are quite a few things to iron out.

Comment: Why do you combine raisebox and valign=c? Wouldn't valign=t already give the desired top alignment of text and image?

Comment: The image should be center aligned, not top

Comment: The example text in your table sais something else...

Comment: Sh*t, I'm sorry. Yes this was my first intention but I found that it doesn't look good, especially if I have one image for multirow. I change the text. My main concern currently is the margin if the image height is > text height.

Comment: @Bibi, what exactly should I be looking for in `booktabs`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- why you use `xtabular` table environment?

  - Is table longer that one page? In this case is better to put captions above table on  each page where it is continued, that is clear visible that table is continued from previous page (see MWE below)
  - If table is shorter, than is better to enclose it in `table` float and use `tabularx` table environment.
- It is not clear, how you like to have aligned images in table:

  - Horizontal centered (since images widths are equal to column width, this is default position)?
  - Vertical centered? This is vague, haw you imagine how this should to be (if the text in the first cell is only in one line, how than image should be positioned in respect to this line?
- The code for image placement in your table is not clear and not provide useful information, consequently below are two possible solution (from among I would use the first one) which uses `\adjustimage` command from `adjustboox` for placement as well for drawing frame around image):

  - text and images are top aligned

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}           
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, xltabular}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttablex}     % to have a dedicated notes section after tables
\usepackage[font=small, margin=0pt]{caption}% table and figure captions
\captionsetup[table]{singlelinecheck=false}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}                  % used for table alternatively colors
\usepackage{adjustbox}              % it loads graphicx too

% Spacing and margin rules
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{7pt}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{10pt}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{5pt}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \section{Place Images in Table}
\begingroup
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}   % distance of box border from content
\setlength{\fboxrule}{1pt}  % box border thicknes
\adjustboxset{width=\dimexpr\linewidth-\tabcolsep\relax,
              valign=t
              }
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{} XXX @{}}
\caption{Test}
\label{test}                \\
    \toprule
\thead{Text} & \thead{Image} & \thead{Image} \\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{Test (cont.)}    \\
    \toprule
\thead{Text} & \thead{Image} & \thead{Image} \\
    \midrule
\endhead
    \bottomrule
\multicolumn{3}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{continue on the next page}}
\endfoot
    \bottomrule
\endlastfoot
%%%% table body
This is some text that should be top-aligned in the cell with the image center aligned in it's own cell. Let's make it a little bit longer \dots\newline
I always want a little bit more \dots 
    & \adjustimage{cfbox=red}{example-image-duck}
        & \adjustimage{cfbox=blue}{example-image-duck} \\
    \cmidrule{1-2} % why, nicer is use just \midrule
This might be a row with some less text
    & \adjustimage{cfbox=teal}{example-image-duck}
        & 
\end{xltabular}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

- text and images are vertical centered. In this case in above MWE you need to replace `\adjustboxset` and `xltabular` specifications with:

```
\adjustboxset{width=\dimexpr\linewidth-\tabcolsep\relax,
              valign=c
              }
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{} m{0.33\linewidth}CC @{}}% or {@{} m{0.33\linewidth}XX @{}}, result is the same
```

[image]

**Addendum:**

In aligning of cells content you actually align baseline of their content. In the first example they are at top in the each column, and in the second are in the middle in each column. Consequently, the second example solve your request if a text in the cells in the first column is higher then images in cells in the other  columns.

That the second solution works also when text in lower than height of images, then you need in this rows to change baseline position of images defined by `valign=...` from `valign=c` to `valign=t` and enclose the text in the first column in `\parbox` if text in cell has more than one line. As example see MWE below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, xltabular}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttablex}     % to have a dedicated notes section after tables
\usepackage[font=small, margin=0pt]{caption}% table and figure captions
\captionsetup[table]{singlelinecheck=false}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}                  % used for table alternatively colors
\usepackage{adjustbox}              % it loads graphicx too

\begin{document}
    \section{Place Images in Table}
\begingroup
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}   % distance of box border from content
\setlength{\fboxrule}{1pt}  % box border thicknes
\adjustboxset{width=\dimexpr\linewidth-\tabcolsep\relax,
              valign=c
              }
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{} m{0.33\linewidth}XXX @{}}% or {@{} m{0.33\linewidth}XX @{}}, \caption{Test}
\label{test}                \\
    \toprule
\thead{Text} & \thead{Image} & \thead{Image} \\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{Test (cont.)}    \\
    \toprule
\thead{Text} & \thead{Image} & \thead{Image} \\
    \midrule
\endhead
    \bottomrule
\multicolumn{3}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{continue on the next page}}
\endfoot
    \bottomrule
\endlastfoot
%%%% table body
This is some text that should be top-aligned in the cell with the image center aligned in it's own cell. Let's make it a little bit longer \dots\newline
I always want a little bit more \dots
    & \adjustimage{cfbox=red}{example-image-duck}
        & \adjustimage{cfbox=blue}{example-image-duck} \\
    \midrule
\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{This might be a row with some less text}    % <--- manually adjusted
    & \adjustimage{cfbox=teal,valign=t}{example-image-duck}     % <--- manually adjusted
        &
\end{xltabular}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is the above result what you looking for?

Comment: I use the `xtabular` because the document might contain long tables, and the caption has to be below the table because this is corperate design - I just try to get a usable template. I like your approach, but is there an easy way to have the image vertically centered while having the text still top aligned? Should also work for images in a multirow cell. The manual approach would be to set `margin` of the `adjustimage` to the desired value, but that seems cumbersome.

Comment: @po.pe, my answer contain two possible solution of vertical positioning of images in `xltabular` table.  As far as I know, there not exist any other (automatic) solution. However, you can manually adjust each such row separately.  See addendum in my answer.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, but the more I have to deal with latex tables I have to learn that it get pretty fast extremely complicated. Is there a guide out there somewhere that covers such use cases? Or you can one learn something like this?

Comment: @po.pe,   you can lear from examples in my answer. For introduction to writing of tables see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables. About design of nice tables is worth to look  https://wiert.me/2014/04/03/andre-vatter-google-wie-tabellen-eigentlich-aussehen-sollten-%EF%BB%BF/ and when you stuck in your effors, here is TeX. SE where you can ask for help :-)

Comment: The difficulty I have is that sometimes solving an issue that is a just little bit different from the last one might has a 180° different solution. And adding new packages sometimes impacts formerly fine running sections of tex. That's where I struggle the most...

Answer (score 2):

Is this what is intended

--you can experiment withe the rule width(set now at 2pt) and padding(set 0mm)

```
    \fboxsep=0mm%padding thickness
    \fboxrule=2pt%border thickness
```

--the first color (blue) is attached to the the image fboxrule and the second color (black) attached to the fboxsep

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{threeparttable}  
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}  

\fboxsep=0mm%padding thickness
\fboxrule=2pt%border thickness

\begin{document}        
\begin{tabular}{p{1.5in}p{3in}p{1.5in}}\toprule 
AAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA&
\fcolorbox{blue}{black}{\includegraphics[width=3in,valign=t]{example-image-a}}&
BBBBBBBBBBB BBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBBBBB\\\midrule 
AAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA&
\includegraphics[width=3in,valign=t]{example-image-a}&
BBBBBBBBBBB BBBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBBB\\\bottomrule 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't get a proper margin/padding using the `\fboxsep` command. Maybe I'm doing something wrong `{\fboxsep=1mm\raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[scale=1.0, cfbox=blue 2pt 2pt, valign=c]{./content/figures/terminate.png}}}`

Comment: theres a mismatch between your code and mine